# How to replace row with another row in linux

Tags: linux, text-processing

I have file 1:

```
 A1  1  NA
 A1  2  NA
 A1  3  NA
 A1  4  A
 A1  5  G
 A1  6  T
 A1  7  NA
 A1  8  NA
 A1  9  NA
 A2  1  NA
 A2  2  NA
 A2  3  T
 A2  4  NA
```

And file 2:

```
A1  4  A
A1  5  B
A1  6  T
A2  3  T
```

I want to replace row number 4,5,6 and 3 of A2 from file 1 with a value of 4,5,6 and 3 from file 2

**Expected Output in new file3:-**

```
A1  1  NA
A1  2  NA
A1  3  NA
A1  4  A
A1  5  B
A1  6  T
A1  7  NA
A1  8  NA
A1  9  NA
A2  1  NA
A2  2  NA
A2  3  T
A2  4  NA
```

The file 1 has 1 Lakh rows for each values in column 1 (Values are  A1 to A13) in file 1. I have only represented just for example. 
file 2 has only few rows of file 1 with values changing in column 3 of file 2.

I want to try this in Linux or python . 
Actually the answer is already posted by some people. And the answer were excellent.

Even i tried using awk and python q command
But i could not resolve this its taking long time to get the result and result file is of 0 byte.

I kept it for 12 hours but still i have not got any result.

**Few Line from my original data**

File1

```
 A01  1  C
 A01  2  T
 A01  3  A
 A01  4  A
 A01  5  A
 A01  6  A
 A01  7  C
 A01  8  A
 A01  9  C
 A01  10  G
 A01  11  C
 A01  12  G
 A01  13  G
 A01  14  A
 A01  15  T
 A01  16  C
 A01  17  C
 A01  18  T
 A01  19  T
 A01  20  C
 A01  21  G
 A01  22  G
 A01  23  G
 A01  24  T
 A01  25  C
 A01  26  G
 A01  27  G
 A01  28  G
 A01  29  T
 A01  30  C
 A01  31  G
  .
  .
  .
 A01 60534289  T
```

File 2

```
 A01  905  T
 A01  911  A
 A01  922  C
 A01  953  C
 A01  967  T
 A01  979  C
 A01  1046  T
 A01  1160  G
 A01  1165  T
 A01  1167  T
 A01  1171  C
 A01  1282  A
 A01  1382  T
 A01  1408  C
 A01  1743  T
 A01  1804  C
 A01  3089  G
 A01  3109  T
 A01  3243  A
 A01  3276  T
 A01  3302  T
 A01  3356  G
 A01  3373  G
 A01  3399  G
 A01  3631  C
 A01  3677  G
 A01  3682  G
 .
 .
 .
 A01  605342 B
```

So in file 2 if it is T in 905 position

```
 A01  905  T
```

and in file 1 if it is B in 905 position

```
 A01  905  B
```

It should replace B to T in file 1 in that particular position without altering another positions values 
Altering another position value in the sense suppose i have
 file1

```
A01   10905  C
```

so for this position it in file 1 it should only change if the 10**905** is there in file2 with other alphabets

Comment: cross posted https://stackoverflow.com/q/49486532/4023950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't add comments here yet, so here's my `awk` solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49486532/how-to-replace-row-with-another-row-in-linux/49486655) that I've tested against your sample input and output:

```
cat file1 file2 | awk '
    BEGIN { OFS = "  " }
    { rows[$1 OFS $2] = $3 }
    END { for (r in rows) print(r, rows[r]) }
' | sort -V >file3
```

Have you tried this or the other answers posted? If you did, what did the actual output have that you weren't expecting? It might help to give additional information on the data file format if the answers don't work.

Comment: I tried this but i am not getting any output. File3 has 0 bytes

Comment: Can you elaborate on the format of the data files then? I'm assuming there's some key information missing. If possible, a sample of the actual contents would help, too.

Comment: data has 13lakhs rows and 3 columns

Comment: What about the behavior of the columns themselves, though? Is each line in the form `label1 label2 value`, or is the format different? At this point, a few lines from the file would be very helpful so we can see why it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi i have updated my original data in main questions

Comment: Interesting, I'm not seeing why it wouldn't work. Is it giving an empty file for all solutions you do?

Comment: yes awk is running but it is not genration any file.

Comment: I got result :)

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'NR == FNR{ a[$1, $2] = $3; next }
     ($1, $2) in a{ $3 = a[$1, $2] }1' file2 OFS='  ' file1
```

The output:

```
A1  1  NA
A1  2  NA
A1  3  NA
A1  4  A
A1  5  B
A1  6  T
A1  7  NA
A1  8  NA
A1  9  NA
A2  1  NA
A2  2  NA
A2  3  T
A2  4  NA
```

Comment: Thanks in one of my sample now its running its giving me result.Let me see if it runs for other samples as well.